# Loading MPEG-4 H264 with SDL or Open Media Layer on Windows, is this possible?

Tags: sdl, h.264, mpeg-4

I want to programmatically load the MPEG-4 H264 video format. I want to know if anyone has tried it or knows if it is possible with SDL or Open Media Layer APIs on Windows.

Comment: Don't understand, what would you like to do? SDL doesn't natively understand mpeg-4 container-format nor raw .264...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like [this tutorial about using SDL and ffmpeg](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/).